# Optimize hyper-parameters of a decision tree

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, decision-tree, gridsearchcv

I am trying to use to sklearn grid search to find the optimal parameters for the decision tree.

```py
Dtree= DecisionTreeRegressor()
parameter_space = {'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
                   'ccp_alpha': [np.array(pd.Series(np.arange(0,1,0.001)))]}

clf_tree = GridSearchCV(Dtree, parameter_space,cv=5)
clf=clf_tree.fit(X,y)
```

I got the following error. I was wondering if you could help me to resolve this. I appreciate your time.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `'ccp_alpha': [np.arange(0,1,0.001).values]` ??

Comment: try `'ccp_alpha': list(np.linspace(0, 1, 1001))`

Comment: @ChrisA  I should include 'ccp_alpha': list(np.linspace(0, 1, 0.001)) . Am I right?

Comment: @ChrisA I got this warning: C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: DeprecationWarning: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.

Comment: @Barsal no, `np.linspace(0, 1, 0.001)` won't work... the 3rd argument is the number of output values, so It can't be 0.001 (needs to be an integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
parameter_space = {'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'], 'ccp_alpha': np.arange(0, 1, 0.001).tolist()}
```